# New item is not updated in the TreeTableView from while getting data from DB?

Tags: java, javafx

New to javafx in learning stage.I am trying to Update the data from the database but when the call the
getConnection method the list is updated but the Treeitem is not updated in the view.

On the first screen it shows the available Db's but after creating new the tree table view is not updating even after calling the getConnection();

marked the place where needed solution with "//-----------------*Calling Here for Updation*"

Tried

1.Used Refresh();

2.tried to clear the view;

PaneClass.java

```
public class PanesClass extends Application {
    ObservableList<Connections> cList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    DbConnection                dbConnection      = new DbConnection();
    TreeItem                    rootItem          = new TreeItem();
    TreeTableView               activeConnections = new TreeTableView();
    AnchorPane                  firstPane         = new AnchorPane();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        NewConnection               newConnection     = new NewConnection();
        SplitPane                   root              = new SplitPane();
        AnchorPane                  secondPane        = new AnchorPane();
        HBox                        buttonBox         = new HBox();
        BorderPane                  topBar            = new BorderPane();
        Button                      nConnection       = new Button("+");
        buttonBox.getChildren().addAll(nConnection);
        topBar.setTop(buttonBox);

        TreeTableColumn<String, Connections> cNameColoumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Name");

        cNameColoumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

        TreeTableColumn<String, Connections> cStatusColoumn = new TreeTableColumn<>("Status");

        cStatusColoumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("status"));

        activeConnections.getColumns().addAll(cNameColoumn, cStatusColoumn);
        activeConnections.setLayoutX(20);
        activeConnections.setLayoutY(40);

        firstPane.getChildren().addAll(topBar, activeConnections);
        root.getItems().addAll(firstPane, secondPane);

        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 600, 480);

        primaryStage.setScene(sc);
        primaryStage.show();
        activeConnections.setShowRoot(false);

         getconnection();

        nConnection.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                                        try {
                                            newConnection.getConnection(activeConnections);
                                        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
    }

    void getconnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    rootItem.getChildren().clear();
    cList.clear();
    cList = dbConnection.getDatabase();
        for (Connections temp : cList) {
            rootItem.getChildren().add(new TreeItem<Connections>(temp));
            System.out.println(temp);
        }
        activeConnections.setRoot(rootItem);
        activeConnections.refresh();

    }
}
```

NewConnection.java

```
public class NewConnection {
    Connections                 connection = null;
    ObservableList<Connections> cList      = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    PanesClass                  panesClass = new PanesClass();
    TreeItem<Connections>                    cItem      = null;
    TreeItem rootItem = new TreeItem();

    public void getConnection(TreeTableView<Connections> activeConnections) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
    DbConnection dbConnection=new DbConnection();
        Stage    secondaryStage = new Stage();
        VBox     root           = new VBox();
        GridPane cDetails       = new GridPane();
        HBox     actionButtons  = new HBox();
        Button   connect        = new Button("Connect");
        Button   save           = new Button("Save");
        Button   cancel         = new Button("Cancel");

        actionButtons.getChildren().addAll(connect, save, cancel);
        //cList=dbConnection.getDatabase();
        actionButtons.setSpacing(10);

        Label name = new Label("Username : ");

        cDetails.add(name, 0, 0);

        TextField uName = new TextField();

        cDetails.setHgrow(uName, Priority.ALWAYS);
        cDetails.add(uName, 1, 0);
        cDetails.setVgap(10);

        root.getChildren().addAll(cDetails, actionButtons);

        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 500, 200);
        secondaryStage.setScene(sc);
        secondaryStage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);

        secondaryStage.show();
        save.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                             @Override
                             public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                             try {

                    dbConnection.setNewDatabase(uName.getText());

   panesClass.getconnection();//-----------------*Calling Here for Updation*

         } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                 secondaryStage.close();
                 event.consume();
         }              
      });
    }
}
```

Connections.java

```
public class Connections {
   private String name;
   private String password;
   private String url;
public Connections() {
    super();
}
public Connections(String name, String password, String url) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
    this.password = password;
    this.url = url;
}

public Connections(String name) {
    super();
    this.name = name;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}
public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Connections [name=" + name + ", password=" + password + ", url=" + url + "]";
}  
}
```

Comment: whatever you do - don't use refresh (it's emergency api if nothing else helps). Instead, setup your data such that the automatic notification of the view is working - too lazy to wade through this tons of code, please strip it down to a [mcve] with nothing but the barest minimum of code that still exhibits the problem (no need for a db connection, just mock it, no need for fancy visuals/layouts, no need for any interaction except the trigger for the update ..

Comment: Made it as simple as it can! :) thanks by the way @kleopatra checked your profile so that I can contact you on this one!

Comment: good that you keep trying :) But it's still far from minimal (f.i. why 3 buttons when all you want to demonstrate right now is the save? why nested layouts? a simple vbox with treeTableView/input field/safe button would suffice). Actually, I think you are confusing yourself: you seem to have two instances of PanesClass - the one used as application which calls NewConnection and the one instantiated (don't!) and used in NewConnection .. at the end, it's a very similar error as in your previous questions: you don't understand parameter passing. Repeating: do a basic tutorial on java, NOW!